# Import CSV from Linux to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have an Azure SQL Server database and a linux box. I have a csv file on the linux machine that I want to import into SQL Server. I have a table already created where I am going to import this file.

Why does this command return an `Unknown argument: -U`?

```
bcp table in ~/test.csv -U myUsername -S databaseServerName -d dbName -q -c -t
```

When I rearrange the arguments passed to bcp like below, it returns an `Unknown argument: -S`

```
bcp table in ~/test.csv -S databaseServerName -d dbName -U myUsername -q -c -t
```

Comment: Are your slashes going the wrong way in your code, or is that a copy/paste mistake? like ... `c:\folders\use\backslashes\not\forward\slashes\test.csv`

Comment: go read the syntax diagram - you are not providing the information in the correct order. Most importantly - the first argument is either a table, view, or a query. The file and direction follow.

Comment: try not putting a space after the -U   aka -UmyUsername

Comment: bcp does not like your path and filename or the tablename given. Can you try the command with the full unc path? Can you share your tablename? just change some letters to not share the real name, but dont change any punctuation or spacing.

Comment: the order of options used is not important. you CAN have spaces after an option between the option and the value.

Answer (score 0):

So contrary to the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017#U

I hit issues where bcp does not like spaces after the argument names.

https://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/bcp-export/

quote from the article above:

//

> The other syntax sugar is that there is no space after the -S
>   argument.  As seen below
>
> -SMyServerName\MyInstanceName
>
> bcp.exe  "SELECT cast(LastName as char(50)) , cast(FirstName as
>   char(50)) , cast(MiddleName as char(50)) , cast(Suffix as char(50))
>   FROM MyAdventureWorksDB.Person.Person ORDER BY NEWID()" queryout
>   PeopleRock.txt -c -t -T -SMyServerName\MyInstanceName

also

https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/bulk-copy.html#importing-data-table

check your syntax sugar in linux (below example is from above easysoft link)

> ./bcp AdventureWorks.HumanResources.myTeam in ~/myTeam.csv  \
>       -f ~/myTeam.Fmt -U mydomain\myuser -S mymachine\sqlexpress

Note the above has the dbname.schemaname.tablename (before the "in" word above)